# Can I send only byte array with asynchronous Socket class?

Tags: c#

I currently work on a server/client program based on asynchronous socket. As far as I see the send() method of the socket class mainly accept byte buffer. Do I have to convert everything to byte array or is there any other method?

What should I do to send a simple string for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string sendMessage = "This is a clarified example now";
byte[] byteMessage = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sendMessage)
```

Should be all you need.  I, for one, am a fan of 30+ character function calls.

Comment: Indeed. UTF8 is just as compact for English text and also supports every other language in the world.

Comment: @dtb once they settle on an encoding standard, call me.  Until then, the rest of the world speaks english.  Umlauts be damned.

Comment: You can't force ASCII on the whole world just because it's convenient for *you* or because *you* cba to care about non-English speaking countries. UTF8 is available, works for the whole world, and changing your code from ASCII to UTF8 is a matter of five keystrokes.

Comment: So you're telling me because my english language is superior and more condensed than simplified chinese that i should be punished?  If i can express myself in 255 different chars or less, then everyone can.  </sarcasm>

Comment: I find this especially hilarious because i recently fixed a bug that was causing characters from Swedish townname to be displayed incorrectly.